# 405 Method Not Allowed Exception in Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I am working on a laravel application where I have an AJAX call from two different pages of laravel blade, one page runs without any error but the other one throws `405 Method Not Allowed`, I am adding the related files below:

Here is the `post` route:

```
Route::post('/cart', 'HomeController@addToCart')->name('home.cart');
```

Here is the `JS` function:

```
function addToCart(id)
{

$.ajaxSetup({
          headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
          }
        });

    $.ajax({
            url:"cart",
            type:'POST',
            data:{bookId:id}
      })
     .done(function(data){
        cartLength.html(data);
        jQuery('#successCart'+id).html('Book Added to Cart');
        console.log(data);
      });
}
```

When I call this function from the `index.blade.php`, it runs fine, below is the call:

```
<a href="#" class="add-to-cart" onclick="event.preventDefault(); addToCart('{{$book->id}}');">Add To Cart</a>
```

But when I call the same function from `show.blade.php`, it gives me `405 Method Not Allowed`, below is the call to the same function from `show.blade.php`:

```
<a href="#" class="add-to-cart" onclick="event.preventDefault(); addToCart('{{ $book->id }}');" >Add To Cart</a>
```

Any help is appreciated in advance. Thank you.

Comment: Try changing `url:"cart",` to `url:"/cart",`. Without the initial `/`, the browser will se the url as relative from the current page, so if you are on a page, say, `example.com/foo`, it would try and post to `example.com/foo/cart`. Adding the `/` in the beginning will tell the browser to read it as relative from the root: `example.com/cart`

Comment: @MagnusEriksson : Thanks, your comment is helpful, I added /cart but it did not work. Then I added the full path `/wisdom2/public/cart` and it worked.

Comment: instead of type: "POST", set method: "POST"